# Hebrew grammar according to the Rabbanim

Tags: product-recommendation, grammar-dikduk

Is there a comprehensive book which collects all opinions from Rishonim all the way down to our times concerning Hebrew grammar rules?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Do the Rishonim diverge _that_ much on Hebrew grammar?

Comment: The Noda' Bihuda was asked a grammar question that probably most rabbis nowadays couldn't answer, and he wrote back: why are you asking me this when you should ask grammar questions to grammarians not Talmudists, and anyway this is a trivial question and the answer is xyz..